# How I can contract the polygon geometry that approximates and is covered by a specified circle in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, polygon, geometry, spatial

How I can contract the polygon geometry that approximates and is covered by a specified circle in SQL Server?

I have a circle

```
DECLARE @circle geography;

SET @circle = geography::STGeomFromText('CURVEPOLYGON(CIRCULARSTRING(2 4, 4 2, 6 4, 4 6, 2 4))',4326);
```

How I can get `POLYGON` that is covered by this circle?

Comment: Are you looking for a convex hull? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933878.aspx

Comment: Note that Ben's answer requires conversion to SqlGeometry (`SELECT geometry::STGeomFromText(@circle.STAsText(), 4326).STConvexHull();` but can you be more specific to what you mean by contract?  I read from that that you want to shrink it?

Comment: There are SDO_UTIL.CIRCLE_POLYGON function in Oracle which takes circle and tolerance value and returns the polygon geometry that approximates and is covered by a specified circle. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_util.htm#BJEJDEJE  I need the same function in MS SQL SERVER

Comment: @WalentynaJuszkiewicz Understood now.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Requires SQL 2012 or higher.

Now I understand completely what you are looking for, you'll find the STCurveToLine() method useful.

For instance:

```
DECLARE @circle GEOGRAPHY;

SET @circle = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('CURVEPOLYGON(CIRCULARSTRING(2 4, 4 2, 6 4, 4 6, 2 4))',4326);

SELECT @circle.STCurveToLine().STAsText();
```

This will return a POLYGON instance.  Depending on the required accuracy and how complex you want the object to be, you may require the Reduce() function to reduce the number of points.

```
SELECT @circle.STCurveToLine().Reduce(1000); -- Or whatever number is appropriate;
```